Insert build date into resulting setup name
I am using InstallShield Pro 2024 and I would like to know if there is a variable like [CurrentBuiltDate] or [YYMMDD] to insert the current build date into the resulting setup filename from the "Product Configuration" screen as shown in the following image? In the following example the resulting setup name would be MyApp412_241211.exe


You can use automation interface to do this:
ISWiProductConfig.SetupFileName

For more details, Refer this: https://docs.revenera.com/installshield26helplib/helplibrary/IHelpAutoISWiSKU.htm#ref-automationinterface_2917186021_1110665
